# Responsive images with multiple fields

Tags: entities, media, theming

I'm working on a site that has (and must have) three image fields for out three breakpoints. We could call them field_img_mobile, field_img_tablet and field_img_desktop

Is there a way (a module?) that could load the image field corresponding to the breakpoint?

Answer (score 0):

I think [Picture](https://www.drupal.org/project/picture) module help you to solve your query.

Please check [Responsive Images in Drupal with the Picture Module](http://thinkshout.com/blog/2014/07/responsive-images-in-drupal-with-the-picture-module/).

OR you can try these also :

1. [Flickr](https://www.drupal.org/project/flickr)
2. [Responsive images and styles](https://www.drupal.org/project/resp_img)

Comment: I've already used picture, I remember that it works with a single field and multiple image cache. This is the best solution but unfortunately I've to maintain these three different fields.